# Run the project Xcode warning

Tags: ios

Every time I run a project, I always find Xcode prompting this warning.

But I don't quite understand what caused it?

As shown in figure

[image]

Sorry, my reputation is a bit low and I can't just type in the picture.

Xcode warning：

UI API Called form background thread.
-[UIApplication statusBarOrientation] must be used from main thread only

Comment: Press ⇧⌘F, search for `statusBarOrientation`, navigate to the search result, dispatch the line to the main thread.

Comment: call it from main thread

Comment: Its a thread issue. All ui related tasks should be performed on main thread. Use DispatchQueue.main.async{ //Your Code } to perform UI task on main thread.

Comment: @Tuhin Ok, thank you

Answer (score 1):

Please set `-[UIApplication statusBarOrientation]` on main thread. Wherever you set this method that function perform on background thread so such kind of error is occured.

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {


     `-[UIApplication statusBarOrientation]`
}
```